# Capture mouse buttons

Tags: c#, mouseclick-event

I have a form that contains GroupBox1 which also contains Label1, TextBox1 and Button1.
GroupBox1.Enables is false!
Can I capture or simulate Mouse_Click on TextBox1 ?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: I think the answerers are having a bit of difficulty to understand what you want to do, if you rewrite your question adding a bit of context and the functionality you are looking for (for the end user) they may be able to give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a solution

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

//$/t:winexe
//& RunInOwnWindow

namespace PowerAPP
{
    public class MainForm : Form
    {
        #region  Initialization
        private System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox groupBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;

        private static void Main(string [] args)
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new MainForm());
        }
        MainForm()
        {
            groupBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox();
            button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            textBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            textBox2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
            label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();

            // button1
            button1.Name = "Button1";
            button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(101, 90);
            button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 24);
            button1.Text = "button1";

            // textBox1
            textBox1.Name = "TextBox1";
            textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(76, 25);
            textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);

            // label1
            label1.Name = "Label1";
            label1.Bounds = new Rectangle(35, 22, 146, 28);
            label1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            label1.Text = "label1";

            // textBox2
            textBox2.Name = "TextBox2";
            textBox2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(76, 55);
            textBox2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 20);

            // label2
            label2.Name = "Label2";
            label2.Bounds = new Rectangle(35, 52, 146, 28);
            label2.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
            label2.Text = "label2";

            groupBox1.Name = "GroupBox1";
            groupBox1.Controls.Add(button1);
            groupBox1.Controls.Add(textBox1);
            groupBox1.Controls.Add(label1);
            groupBox1.Controls.Add(textBox2);
            groupBox1.Controls.Add(label2);

            groupBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(35, 34);
            groupBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 128);
            groupBox1.Text = "groupBox1";

            // MainFORm
            Name = "MainFOrm";
            ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 266);
            Controls.Add(groupBox1);
            Text = "Click Fields to include";
            MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(MainForm_MouseClick);

            groupBox1.Enabled = false;
        }
        #endregion

        private void MainForm_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point pt = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
            Locate_Point_in_Control_Bounds(this, pt);
        }

        private void Locate_Point_in_Control_Bounds(Control ctl, Point pt)
        {
            Rectangle r;
            if (ctl is Form || ctl.HasChildren)
            {
                foreach (Control c in ctl.Controls)
                {
                    if (c.HasChildren) Locate_Point_in_Control_Bounds(c, pt);
                    r = c.Bounds;
                    r.Offset(ctl.Left, ctl.Top);
                    if (r.Contains(pt))
                        MessageBox.Show(c.Name);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                r = ctl.Bounds;
                r.Offset(ctl.Left, ctl.Top);
                if (r.Contains(pt))
                    MessageBox.Show(ctl.Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd better post an answer instead of a comment.  You won't get any events for the TextBox since you disabled its parent. Technically you can implement the IMessageFilter interface to work around that. But it is rather important that you don't try to work around that, this all works by design and you should *never* be interested in a click on a disabled control.

Your user will never guess in a million years that such a click will do anything useful.  A disabled control makes it *very* obvious that clicking on it is pointless.  As it should.  If there's any click at all then it was probably an accident.  You neither want to implement accidents nor expose features of your code that are completely undiscoverable.

Comment: You are right, but I need that for some admin control and to keep space than add Button for options.

Comment: I don't know what that means.  Maybe it is a language barrier, but it if it is hard to express in words then it is usually hard to write in code as well.  Maybe you ought to think about it for a bit.  And talk to that admin that needs to use it, user feedback is always good.

Comment: Thanks Hans, what I mean is that the Admin will have advanced functions.
I am thinking of graping Mouse_Click point(x,y) and get the rectangle of TextBox1 tho!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this very easy by the following line of code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Disable the groupBox with textBox1 in it
        groupBox1.Enabled = false;

        //Simulate the Click on textBox1
        textBox1_MouseClick(this, new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 1,0,0,0));
    }

    private void textBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test");
    }
```

The code shown above can also be in another control, i used a button1 just for example.

Update 1:
It doesn't matter if the group box is enabled or not, it always catches the event if you call the event directly by textBox1_MouseClick(...).

greetings

Comment: Mario, Thanks for your reply, but GroupBox1.Enabled = false;

Comment: yes i tried it, and it works. i updated the code to proof it.

Comment: Thanks Mario, in fact, GroupBox1 Disabled in Form1_Load